# WPF, merge 3 RenderTargetBitmap to one

Tags: c#, wpf

Hi I have a question.

I have a method(extension) that takes list of FrameworkElement and creates images out of them, then it should create one image out of those images and copy it to clipborad.

My code looks like:

```
    public static void CopyManyUiElementToClipboard(List<FrameworkElement> elements)
    {
        var images = new List<RenderTargetBitmap>();
        elements.ForEach(element =>
        {
            double width = element.ActualWidth;
            double height = element.ActualHeight;
            var size = new Size(width, height);

            var drawingContext = new DrawingVisual();
            using (DrawingContext draw = drawingContext.RenderOpen())
            {
                var visualBrush = new VisualBrush(element);
                draw.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(), size));
            }

            var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height,96d,96d,PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
            var vRect = new Rectangle
            {
                Width = (int)size.Width,
                Height = (int)size.Height,
                Fill = Brushes.White
            };

            vRect.Arrange(new Rect(size));
            renderBitmap.Render(vRect);
            renderBitmap.Render(drawingContext);

            images.Add(renderBitmap);
        });
    }
```

It creates images from all ui elements and add it to collection, but I cant find a way to create one image (im memmory of course).

If I add all images to clipboard in for each loop like

```
 Clipboard.SetImage(renderBitmap);
```

it copies last image (what makes sense, thats why I want to create single image out of 3).

Any ideas?

Comment: You're going to need to arrange all 3 together into one container of some sort. That could be one drawingvisual but it'd contain all 3 somehow - on top of one another, side by side or whatever.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I found a way, for anyone interested:

```
    public static void CopyManyUiElementToClipboard(List<FrameworkElement> elements)
    {
        double totalWidth = elements.First().ActualWidth;
        double totalHeight = elements.Sum(element => element.ActualHeight);

        var size = new Size(totalWidth, totalHeight);
        var rectangleFrame = new Rectangle
        {
            Width = (int)size.Width,
            Height = (int)size.Height,
            Fill = Brushes.White
        };

        rectangleFrame.Arrange(new Rect(size));
        var renderBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)size.Width, (int)size.Height, 96d, 96d, PixelFormats.Pbgra32);
        renderBitmap.Render(rectangleFrame);

        var yPointCordinate = 0.0;
        elements.ForEach(element =>
        {
            var drawingContext = new DrawingVisual();

            using (DrawingContext draw = drawingContext.RenderOpen())
            {
                var visualBrush = new VisualBrush(element);
                var elementSize = new Size(element.ActualWidth, element.ActualHeight);
                draw.DrawRectangle(visualBrush, null, new Rect(new Point(0, yPointCordinate), elementSize));
            }

            yPointCordinate += element.ActualHeight;
            renderBitmap.Render(drawingContext);
        });

        Clipboard.SetImage(renderBitmap);
    }
```

As an argument function takes list of FrameworkElements and for each element it creates sepperate bitmap and renders full picture using y point manipulation, like take  hight of youre last element and make it a start y point of you're new bitmap.

Comment: thanks for posting this solution, ends up being exactly something i've been looking at.